# WorkManager need to work only in between particular time interval, how to use work manager constraints ? Work manager example

Tags: android, location, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I am first time working with Work Manager and I have implemented it successfully.

I am taking location on every 30 Minutes to track employee.

I have started my Work Manager when Database synced first time, but I want to **stop it on every day by evening.**

Here is **MyWorker.java**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "MyWorker";
    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    /**
     * The current location.
     */
    private Location mLocation;
    /**
     * Provides access to the Fused Location Provider API.
     */
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    private Context mContext;

    private String fromRegRegCode, fromRegMobile, fromRegGUID, fromRegImei, clientIP;

    /**
     * Callback for changes in location.
     */
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: Done");
        //mContext.startService(new Intent(mContext, LocationUpdatesService.class));
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob: STARTING JOB..");
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            }
        };

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        try {
            mFusedLocationClient
                    .getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                mLocation = task.getResult();

                                String currentTime = CommonUses.getDateToStoreInLocation();
                                String mLatitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude());
                                String mLongitude = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude());

                                LocationHistoryTable table = new LocationHistoryTable();
                                table.setLatitude(mLatitude);
                                table.setLongitude(mLongitude);
                                table.setUpdateTime(currentTime);
                                table.setIsUploaded(CommonUses.PENDING);

                                LocationHistoryTableDao tableDao = SohamApplication.daoSession.getLocationHistoryTableDao();
                                tableDao.insert(table);

                                Log.d(TAG, "Location : " + mLocation);
                                mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);

                                /**
                                 * Upload on server if network available
                                 */
                                if (Util.isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                                    checkForServerIsUP();
                                }

                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
        }

        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                    null);
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            //Utils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Code for Start Worker:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, repeatInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addTag("Location")
            .build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Location", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, periodicWork);
```

**Is there any particular way to stop it on every day evening?**

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot stop the **Workmanager** for some period of time.

Here is the trick just add this condition in `doWork()` method

Basically you need to check the current time ie is it evening or night if yes dont perform your task.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
    // this condition for evening time and call return here
     return Result.success();
}
else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
    // this condition for night time and return success 
      return Result.success();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Special thanks for snippet.

Comment: i am glad i could help you , try the answer

Comment: The main issue with this solution is that you're going to run the doWork() method even when it's not required. A better solution would be to check for the time in doWork() and, if it outside of the range you want, you schedule a new PeriodicWorkRequest with an initial delay (you need v2.1-alpha02 for this) and return failure. WorkManager will take care of cancelling the current WorkRequest and your Worker will be executed next time when the delay you set expires.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pause the PeriodicWorkRequest and only option is you have to cancel the request.

Solution: Better add the condition check inside the **dowork()** method whether current system time is in between 6pm to 6am don't do anything else do your work like this you have to add the condition check.

or You can use Alarm Manager to start Service at specified time and then repeat alarm in specified interval. When alarm goes on you can start service and connect to server and make what you want

Comment: Still if you have any doubts let me know .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform something at a specific time you can use `AlarmManager` like this :

```
Intent alaramIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AutoLogoutIntentReceiver.class);
    alaramIntent.setAction("LogOutAction");
    Log.e("MethodCall","AutoLogOutCall");
    alaramIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alaramIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Log.e("Logout", "Auto Logout set at..!" + calendar.getTime());
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` class :

```
public class AutoLogoutIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if("LogOutAction".equals(intent.getAction())){

            Log.e("LogOutAuto", intent.getAction());


            //Stops the visit tracking service
            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, VisitTrackingService.class);
            stopIntent.setAction(VisitTrackingService.ACTION_STOP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
            context.startService(stopIntent);

            //logs user out of the app and closes it
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(context).logout();
            exit(context);

        }
    }
```

and don't forget to add the receiver in the manifest (inside application tag) :

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoLogoutIntentReceiver" />
```

For more info regarding alarm manager check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-and-scheduling-alarms-in-android/)

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Will it work for all device? Must be on Android Oreo or Pie

Answer (score 0):

I’d use two Workers. First to manage and second to get location. First would work periodically – every 24 hours at the evening. It would stop the LocationService and call it again with a delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can Start OneTimeRequest worker every morning which would trigger your PeriodicWorkRequest for LocationGathering. and add a time check

```
 //Set initial delay for next OneTimeRequest in DoWork() method which can be calculated as
 public static int initialDelay(){
        int initialDelayMinutes = 0;
        try {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            // Set Execution around 09:00:00 AM
           dueDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dueDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
            dueDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dueDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, ChannelierConstants.AUTO_SYNC_TIMING.DAY_START.getType());
            dueDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            dueDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            int currentDateHour = currentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int dueDateHour = dueDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int currentDateMinutes = currentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            //MyUtils.createLog("DUE HOUR "+dueDateHour,"CURRENT HOuR "+currentDateHour+"\t current minutes is "+currentDateMinutes);
            int diff = Math.abs(dueDateHour - currentDateHour);

            //MyUtils.createLog("HOUR DIFF --  "+diff,"24-diff is "+Math.abs(24 - diff));
            if (dueDate.before(currentDate)) {
                currentDate.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Math.abs(24-diff));
                initialDelayMinutes = ((Math.abs(24 - diff)) * 60) +currentDateMinutes;
            }else {
                initialDelayMinutes = 60 - currentDateMinutes;
            }


            createLog("MINUTES "+initialDelayMinutes,"DUE DATE +"+simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate.getTimeInMillis()));

        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return initialDelayMinutes;
    }
```

also check status of periodicWorkRequest and trigger if not scheduled/ running in OneTimeRequest doWork()

Last but not least check Current time in PeriodicWorkRequest and cancel work if it exceeds the desired time of ending location tracking work

```
  /**
     * This method is used to cancel periodic autosync if current time is before/ after the mentioned sync time
     * */
    public static boolean shouldCancelPeriodicAutoSync(String wrokerTAG,Context context) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        int HOUR_OF_DAY = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        createLog("HOUR OF DAY","--> "+HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (HOUR_OF_DAY > ChannelierConstants.AUTO_SYNC_TIMING.DAY_START.getType() && HOUR_OF_DAY < ChannelierConstants.AUTO_SYNC_TIMING.DAY_END.getType()){
            return true;
        }else {
            createLog("Cancelling Periodic Sync ",""+wrokerTAG);
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelUniqueWork(wrokerTAG);
            return false;
        }
    }
```